# Laravel Ajax request via AngularJS $http

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, validation, laravel

I've been struggling for hours on how to get my validation working.
Here's an image:

[image: Error]

As you can see on the image, I sent a 'password' and 'token' fields to the server, but it seems like it doesn't "see" the password when it is passed on the server side?

This is the code I have for sending request to the server,

```
app.controller('UsersProfilesUsersController', function($scope, $http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
      $scope.credentials = {'_token' : CSRF_TOKEN, 'password': 'haha'};
      $scope._user = 'user';

      $scope.submitUsersProfilesUser = function (){
        console.log($scope.credentials);
        var data = $scope.credentials;
        $http.post('/users/users_profiles/20/edit', data).then(function (data){
          console.log(data);
        }, function(data) {
          console.log('error!');

          console.log(data);
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
       };

    });
```

And this is my code when receiving the data server side (Note: using laravel framework)

```
public function store(Request $request){   
    $this->validate($request, [
       'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6', 
    ]);
    return $request;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: token can be get on server side or not?

Comment: It seems to me that validation is simply not passing, what happens if you send valid credentials? P.S. The `confirmed` rule requires one more _confirmation_ field, are you aware of that?